# Each page of my website is indexed in Google under multiple domain names. How to fix this with .htaccess?

Tags: seo

Each page of my website is indexed in Google under multiple domain names with redundant entries. I am assuming this is a problem.  Would I use .htaccess to fix this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to specify the primary URL for each page.

Comment: I probably didn't explain the problem correctly.
The page you recommended says to put a canonical link tag 
"...inside the <head> section of the duplicate content URLs..."
The redundant entries aren't separate pages.
I have two domain names.
Google has indexed each page on my server using both domains.
For example, my home page shows up twice:
 www.riversonfineart.com/index.php
 www.riversonfinemosaics.com/index.php
Am I supposed to edit each of my 300+ pages an put canonical link tags for each redundant URL?
For example:
<link rel="canonical" href="www.riversonfineart.com/index.php" />

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying